# Playing MP3 Shield tracks

Tags: shields

I have an MP3 shield on a Arduino Uno. When using "File Player" I can get the tracks to play by keyboard entry with three digits (001-009).

The problem is that I want to use (SFEMP3Shield > examples > MP3ButtonPlayer2) that is looking for files 1-9. Any file numbers other than 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 doesn’t work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Arduino:SE.  Please post the code that you are trying to use.  You might find this post on our Meta site helpful: [How to ask a good question for Arduino Stack Exchange](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2523/how-to-ask-a-good-question-for-arduino-stack-exchange).

Answer (score 1):

The `playTrack` function used in MP3ButtonPlayer2 example plays file with name created with printf format "track%03d.mp3". %03d creates a number prefixed with zeros to lenght 3. For example track005.mp3 or track042.mp3 or track999.mp3.

implementation of the playTrack function:

```
uint8_t SFEMP3Shield::playTrack(uint8_t trackNo){

  //a storage place for track names
  char trackName[] = "track001.mp3";
  uint8_t trackNumber = 1;

  //tack the number onto the rest of the filename
  sprintf(trackName, "track%03d.mp3", trackNo);

  //play the file
  return playMP3(trackName);
}
```

change it to:

```
uint8_t SFEMP3Shield::playTrack(uint8_t trackNo){

  //a storage place for track names
  char trackName[13];
  int trackNumber = trackNo;

  //tack the number onto the rest of the filename
  sprintf(trackName, "track%03d.mp3", trackNumber);

  //play the file
  return playMP3(trackName);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, makes sense, but I'm not a programmer, I don't know how to edit the SFEMP3Shield > examples > MP3ButtonPlayer2 to make it work.

Comment: put the SD card in a computer and rename the files. You should buy an MP3 player, not an Arduino, if you don't want to code

Comment: It's part of a larger program that uses code that I have worked out. This is the only thing I haven't been able to work, although Sparkfun says it should out of the box. It just need to play 3 tracks when things happen. I have renamed the tracks may times. Does the code you gave go on the SD card or into the MP3ButtonPlayer2 code?

Comment: it doesn't go anywhere. it is in the library. (and it's a shame for the author of the library, because it should not be coded as it is)

Comment: The SFEMP3Shield library is included in the sketch. What am I supposed to rename the tracks to? When I run File Player I get;

Comment: Received command: l 
Music Files found :
00001: SndoSil.mp3
00002: Stmup.mp3
00003: Blndblt.mp3
I have renamed the files 001,002,003 with no change.

Comment: The 5 digit number is not on the SD card. It is generated in file player.

Comment: it should be track001.mp3

Comment: It’s not, that’s my point.I have renamed it track001.mp3 and somewhere in the upload it appears as track00001.mp3. Sparkfun tech support told me to input two leading zeros and since I proved the shied works they're done and told me to figure it out myself. Do you know how to add two leading zeros @ int8_t track = 0; in the MP3ButtonPlayer2 sketch?

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SFEMP3Shield\SFEMP3Shield.cpp: In member function 'uint8_t SFEMP3Shield::vs_init()':

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SFEMP3Shield\SFEMP3Shield.cpp:292:34: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

   if(VSLoadUserCode("patches.053")) return 6;

Comment: function `playTrack` will add two leading zeros, if you have the same library. call it as `playTrack(1)`, `playTrack(2)`, `playTrack(3)`,

Comment: It needs to add two "ADDITIONAL" zeros. The library is SFEMP3Shield and I have downloaded it from many places and having different dates. here is what I get from "FilePlayer" 
Received command: l 
Music Files found :
00001: SndoSil.mp3
00002: Stmup.mp3
00003: Blndblt.mp3
00004: track001.mp3
Sparkfun told me that they noticed it was adding additional zeros and to input two additional zeros via keyboard in "FilePlayer"  and it would work which it does but I want to use MP3ButtonPlayer2 which generates it's own number and doesn't work.

Comment: The MP3ButtonPlayer2 sketch does call for playTrack(1), playTrack(2), playTrack(3) it should cal for playTrack(001), playTrack(002), playTrack(003) or the SFEMP3Shield library need to be fixed.

Comment: the parameter of function playTrack is int. the function builds the name as you see in my answer. read the answer again

Comment: I've read your answer several times.I understand the sketch does add two zeros. it needs to add two MORE zeros or the SFEMP3Shield library needs to be fixed.

Comment: but SD card supports only 8 characters long names (plus file extension)

Comment: from where do you have the library?

Comment: The names are 8 characters or less. The five digit number shouldn't be there. I didn't put it there. Like I said, I have downloaded from several places older & newer versions all with the same result. Could you send me a link to where you believe I can get a right one?

Comment: https://github.com/madsci1016/Sparkfun-MP3-Player-Shield-Arduino-Library

Comment: Thank You, I'll download and replace existing library.

Comment: Did it. No change!

Comment: so MP3ButtonPlayer2 example doesn't play track001.mp3? is the file a valid mp3 file? or you have some other sketch? if yes, add it to Question

Comment: Yes MP3ButtonPlayer2 example doesn't play track001.mp3 that is a valid mp3 file. As explained above it does play using "File Player" when I serial input  0000X.

Comment: and you have buttons connected to A0, A1, A2? And when you press button on A2 it prints "B_NEXT pressed, Start Playing Next Track #1" and doesn't play?

Comment: Yes, buttons are connected to A0, A1, A2? And when A2 is pressed it prints "B_NEXT pressed, Start Playing Next Track #1" and doesn't play

Comment: can you make a small modification to playTrack function in library? change `char trackName[] = "track001.mp3";` to `char trackName[13];`

Comment: Where? Examples, keywords, SFEMP3Shield.cpp, SFEMP3Shield.h, SFEMP3ShieldConfig.h, SFEMP3Shieldmainpage.h

Comment: SFEMP3Shield.cpp

Comment: next you can try to change the parameter type from `uint8_t trackNo` to `int trackNo`, because that is right for sprintf.

Comment: Okay, I found it in SFEMP3Shield.cpp and can only open in wordpad or notepad When I change it it won't let me save because I don't have administrator permission

Comment: uint8_t trackNo to int trackNo is that in the sketch?

Comment: I changed uint8_t track =0; to int track =0; in the sketch. No change.

Comment: Okay, I opened SFEMP3Shield.cpp with visual studio and changed char trackName[] = "track001.mp3"; to char trackName[13]; No change.

Comment: Do you know what this means? C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SFEMP3Shield\SFEMP3Shield.cpp: In member function 'uint8_t SFEMP3Shield::vs_init()':

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SFEMP3Shield\SFEMP3Shield.cpp:292:34: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

   if(VSLoadUserCode("patches.053")) return 6;

Comment: variable track is unused. you should change the parameter trackNo

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what that means.

Comment: There is no trackNo in the sketch

Comment: the snippet in my answer. first line

Comment: `uint8_t SFEMP3Shield::playTrack(uint8_t trackNo){` to `uint8_t SFEMP3Shield::playTrack(int trackNo){`

Comment: There is no "trackNo" in the sketch are you referring to somewhere else?

Comment: in SFEMP3Shield.cpp playTrack

Comment: will not compile. 'uint8_t SFEMP3Shield::playTrack(int)' does not match any in class 'SFEMP3Shield'

Comment: sorry, I forgot that it will require change in the .h. I add to answer a modified version of the playTrack function. try this

Comment: I'm sorry, I can cut and paste, but I need to know what & where.

Comment: from the Answer to SFEMP3Shield.cpp

Comment: I don't know what the Answer to SFEMP3Shield.cpp is.

Comment: copy/paste from answer, here on SE. my Answer to your Question. I edited it. scroll up

Comment: I'm lost, Where is here on SE?

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/57147/playing-mp3-shield-tracks/57148#57148

Comment: still lost, I went through that before, you said will require change in the .h.

Comment: which we do not make, instead we use the unused variable to have type int. sprintf doesn't like uint8_t

Comment: I'm not a programmer, I don't know what any of that means, sorry.

Comment: I'm sure I made all the changes you specified with the following result; C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SFEMP3Shield\SFEMP3Shield.cpp: In member function 'uint8_t SFEMP3Shield::vs_init()':
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SFEMP3Shield\SFEMP3Shield.cpp:292:34: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
 if(VSLoadUserCode("patches.053")) return 6;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SFEMP3Shield\SFEMP3Shield.cpp: At global scope:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SFEMP3Shield\SFEMP3Shield.cpp:1025:9:

Comment: error: prototype for 'uint8_t SFEMP3Shield::playTrack(int)' does not match any in class 'SFEMP3Shield'
uint8_t SFEMP3Shield::playTrack(int trackNo){
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SFEMP3Shield\SFEMP3Shield.cpp:9:0:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SFEMP3Shield\SFEMP3Shield.h:691:13: error: candidate is: uint8_t SFEMP3Shield::playTrack(uint8_t)
uint8_t playTrack(uint8_t);
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.

Comment: yes. the parameter must be uint8_t. revert this change. the first 'error' is only a warning. it was always there

Comment: It seems I'm going in circles, we're right back where we were. Are you able to make the changes you want to SFEMP3Shield\SFEMP3Shield.cpp and give me a link to it so you can be sure it's the way you want it? I still believe the problem is the 5 digit index. Where is that generated?

Comment: it is generated in FilePlayer example with `SerialPrintPaddedNumber(count, 5 );`

Comment: I cannot find SerialPrintPaddedNumber(count, 5 ); in FilePlayer example.

Comment: I do find it in SFEMP3Shield\SFEMP3Shield.cpp Line 184& Line 621

Comment: I would expect the index to change when I change the 5 to 3 but it does not.

Comment: Are you able to make the changes you want to SFEMP3Shield\SFEMP3Shield.cpp and give me a link to it so you can be sure it's the way you want it?

Comment: in the Answer is the original and the modified version of playTrack function

Comment: SerialPrintPaddedNumber is the last function in the sketch. this numbering is nothing general. it is the way the sketch uses to get user's choice

Comment: Where is the Answer?

Comment: we are commenting it here. scroll up

Comment: reloaded SFEMP3Shield\SFEMP3Shield.cpp modified playTrack function from above. No progress, MP3ButtonPlayer2 does everything but play. I asked you before, do you know how to add leading zeros to a string?

Comment: yes. the playTrack function does it as you can see in Answer and the SerialPrintPaddedNumber function in FilePlayer example does it too